# Looping through List and creating views dependent on the data

Tags: java, list

I currently have two Lists:

```
List<String> listUserAnswers = splitWords(answer);
List<String> listRealAnswers = splitWords(realAnswer);
```

My main goal is to loop through these and create different views dependent on the data. For example, for each correctAnswer I will create one kind of view, and for incorrectAnswer, another.

I then loop through both the Lists:

```
for (String userAnswer : listUserAnswers) {
        for (String realAnswer : listRealAnswers) {
            if (userAnswer.equals(realAnswer)) {
                correctLayout = createCorrectView(userAnswer);
                newCorrectViews.add(correctLayout);
            } else {
                incorrectLayout = createIncorrectView(userAnswer);
                newIncorrectViews.add(incorrectLayout);
            }
        }
    }
```

I then check if the userAnswer matches the realAnswer, and then create the views.

However, the problem I'm experiencing is that if the realAnswer is:

```
[This, Is, The, Real, Answer]
```

and a user enters:

```
[This, Is, Real]
```

Then the first two words should show up on the screen as being correct, and the word 'Real' incorrect.

However, what's actually happening is:

`[This, Is, This, This, Is, Is, Real, Real]` -> where `[This, Is]` are correct and the rest are marked as incorrect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have an inner loop. You just need a loop for both so don't use an enhance one.

You can use something like:

```
minSize = listUserAnswers.size() > listRealAnswers.size() ? listUserAnswers.size() : listRealAnswers.size();
for(int i = 0; i < minSize; i++)
  String userAnswer = listUserAnswers.get(i);
  String realAnswer = listRealAnswers.get(i);
  if(userAnswer.equals(realAnswer))
     ....
```

which just checks for the actual words in the same position.

Comment: Ah nice, this makes so much sense! Cheers :)